# i am getting this error after replacing new version with previous version in virtual emulator

Tags: android

05/21 11:38:15: Launching 'app' on Pixel_3a_API_33_arm64-v8a.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.

List of apks:

Installation failed due to: ''package install-create -r -t --user current --full --dont-kill --skip-verification -S 6309515' returns error 'Unknown failure: cmd: Can't find service: package''
Retry
Failed to launch an application on all devices

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me !

Wipe data for the emulator: If restarting the emulator doesn't work, you can try wiping the data for the emulator. Go to the AVD Manager in Android Studio, select the Pixel_3a_API_33_arm64-v8a emulator, and click on the "Wipe Data" button. This will reset the emulator to its initial state.